# Let $(G,\ast )$ a group and $H$ a normal subgroup in $G$. If $K$ is a subgroup in $G$ containing $H$ then $K$ is normal in $G$

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups

I've tried show a counterexample using the dihedrical group of order 12, but the proposition seems true.

How I can start to prove that? My problem in the proof is show that the elements in $K-H$ satisfy that $x^-1 \ast k\ast x \in K ; \forall k\in K$.

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $H =\{ e \}$ is always normal in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but, exist another counterexample?

Comment: @testpilot Yes. $H= \{ e \} \times G'$ is always normal in $G \times G'$, no matter what $G'$ is.

Comment: @testpilot And there are many counterexamples with $H= Z(G)$.

Comment: @testpilot In general, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/H$ is simple,  then $H,G$ is counterexample to your claim. The simplest way to produce counterexamples is by making sure that $H$ is a direct summand in $G$, that's why the direct products are natural examples. So you can add to the above list any group of the form $H=H_1 \times \{ e \}$ in $G=H_1 \times H_2$ with $H_2$ simple and non-abelian.

Comment: @testpilot You can also consider an onto homomorphism $\phi : G \to G_1$ where $G_1$ is any simple non-abelian group. Then $H=\ker(\phi)$ is a counterexample.